# Multi-bank vs multibank

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

Which do you think is the correct version to be used in the following sentence?

> ABC Company offers XYZ, a **multi-bank**/**multibank** payment system.

And how should these versions be used?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

It depends what multi-bank (or multibank) **is**.

If you're referring to a "thing" that applies to lots of different banks, then you would say "multi-bank", using the standard "multi-" prefix.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/multi-

There's a caveat to this:  if multi- prefix words get used widely enough, for long enough, then the hyphen tends to disappear and they enter the lexicon as a single word rather than a hyphenated compound word.  Thus we have "multiagency", "multidimensional" etc.  This is a slow process with no clear dividing line.  If there's any doubt, it's more clear for the reader if you use the hyphen.

If someone has actually **named** the system "Multibank", (ie has invented a banking product and called it "Multibank" then it's a pronoun and you use the capital letter (with pronouns there are no rules for spelling etc - it just is what it is and you always just copy that).

Answer (score 0):

Searching *multibank, multi bank*, and *multi-bank* everyone use **multibank and multi-bank**.

So, spellchecker says that *multibank* is wrong, while *multi-bank* and *multi bank* aren't.

If you use *multi bank*, You can be sure it's right.